# Multiverse and the anthropic principle?

Tags: philosophy-of-physics, cosmology, multiverse, anthropology

In this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0211048) by physicist Andrei Linde, the multiverse concept, the anthropic principle, quantum cosmology and inflationary cosmology are discussed.

In the paper, he analyzes a multiverse with a large landscape of universes (described by different spaces and dimensions, different lagrangians, different actions, different types of evolution…)

He mentions and analyzes various models of theoretical physics (like inflation cosmology, quantum cosmology, Wheeler-DeWitt equation…) but does not clarify whether any of these models could be applied to the vast multiverse he is describing. He neither does specify which of these models could produce such variety of hypothetical universes nor if any of them could produce it.

Also, John's Barrow book "The Constants of Nature" in chapter 13, he talks about a hypothetical multiverse composed of universes governed by other logics. Specifically, he talks about different approaches that physicists take when studying the multiverse, and he mentions a radical approach where even logic could change from one universe to another. But he does not specify any multiverse model...So what is he talking about? Is it there any multiverse model where even the fundamental logic of universes could change?

So my question is:

Is it there any theory/model/equation that could produce such a vast multiverse? Any model that Linde mentions? Could Wheeler-DeWitt equation be an option for that?

Comment: Thanks for the Linde link. What a great article. Lucid and insightful. I learned more about multiverse theory from that than from all the Youtube videos and forum discussions I've seen.